# python decrypt AES

Tags: python, encryption, aes

This is my code:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random
import base64

Plain_text = "Text"
random = Random.new()
IV = random.read(AES.block_size)
KEY = base64.b64encode(random.read(AES.key_size[0]))
Cipher = AES.AESCipher(KEY, AES.MODE_CFB, IV)
print "Key:", KEY

Encrypting = Cipher.encrypt(Plain_text)
print "Encrypting:\n",Encrypting


#KEY2 = base64.b64decode(KEY)
#IV2 = random.read(AES.block_size)
#print "KEY2:", KEY2
Cipher2 = AES.AESCipher(base64.b64decode(KEY), AES.MODE_CFB, IV)
Decrypting = Cipher2.decrypt(Encrypting)
print "Decrypting:\n", Decrypting
```

Script output:

```
Output is:
Key: VYy9unePPuKiQHwVcqkJzA==
Encrypting:
�F!C
Decrypting:
���
```

Why script can not decrypt?

```
OS = Ubuntu 16.04

Python Version = 2.7.12
```

Comment: Well, I guess one thing is you're unencoding the key, but you encrypted it with the base64 string.

Comment: so don't decode the base64 key because you're changing the cipher

Answer (score 1):

The key supplied to the AES function should be in binary format. In your case you are encoding the key to base-64 first. In the encryption, it seems that you accidentally use this encoded string as the key.

Fixed code snippet:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random
import base64

plaintext = "Text"
random = Random.new()
iv = random.read(AES.block_size)
key = random.read(AES.key_size[0])
cipher = AES.AESCipher(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)

key_b64 = base64.b64encode(key)
print ("Key: {}".format(key_b64))

ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(plaintext)
print("Encrypting: {}".format(ciphertext))
```